# Reporting Services: Exported to Excel results are different than the ones viewed on IE

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, debugging, reporting-services, reporting

I'm having this problem:

The SQL Server holds a said value, let's say 990.30, the Reporting Services Report show a different value (948.33) when viewed online, in the brower and a third value (912.22) when the report is exported to Excel.

There are no formulas on Excel, just plain values.
Also, there's no formula on the layout of the report.
The code shows only a simple select that, when run on the SQL Server Management Studio, returns me the original value (990.30).

How on earth shall I start to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: I just exported to PDF and got yet other different values. This is Madness! (with persian messenger awe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of this kind of problem before.  I would recommend submitting a ticket to Microsoft and provide them with screen shots of the errors, the RDL file, a sample output of the stored procedure, etc.

To troubleshoot this on your own, I would recommend creating a new report that just has a simple table that returns all the details from your stored procedure or query to validate the values are consisten across all interfaces.  From there, just start adding on complexity until you get the report to look like it is today.